# How to get method results with AsyncCallback?

Tags: c#

I hope you can help me with the following:

I have a WebService method which is supposed to return an array of CompensationPlanReturnReturn objects.
The method is called like this:

```
//This is the object I need to instanciate  because it contains the method I wanna call
CompensationPlan_Out_SyncService test = new CompensationPlan_Out_SyncService();
//This is the method that is supposed to return me an array of CompensationPlanReturnReturn objects
//The data.ToArray() is the parameter the method need, then I pass the method that I wanna run when the method finishes and I dont know what to pass as the final parameter
test.BeginCompensationPlan_Out_Sync(data.ToArray(), new AsyncCallback(complete), null)

//The method description is:
public System.IAsyncResult BeginCompensationPlan_Out_Sync(CompensationPlanDataCompensationPlan[] CompensationPlanRequest, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)

//On this method I'd like to access to the resuls (the array of CompensationPlanReturnReturn) but I dont know how
private void complete(IAsyncResult result)
    {            
        lblStatus.Text = "Complete";
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `test.EndCompensationPlan_Out_Sync(result)`, which will return the result of the asynchronous operation, or throw an exception if an error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

Async methods breakdown into two submethods - `Begin` and `End`.

You need to call `EndCompensationPlan_Out_Sync` to get the actual result returned by method -

```
private void complete(IAsyncResult result)
{            
    var actualResult = test.EndCompensationPlan_Out_Sync(result);
    lblStatus.Text = "Complete";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the AsyncState-Property and cast it the the given Type.

Like this:

```
cSACommand = (SACommand)Result.AsyncState;
```

Comment: That isn't the result.

Comment: This will fail with `NullReference Exception` since OP passed `AsyncState` as null. And as mentioned by @Slaks this is not actual result.

Comment: @RohitVats: It won't throw an exception; it will simply be null.